# Retrieving data in Python from two MySQL tables?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm using Python and I'm trying to retrieve data from two mySQL tables(name = deal_info and profile) in the same database (name = begin). The two tables are not linked or do NOT have the same primary key, but I get the error

```
  raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found.")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found.
```

Below is the code

```
import mysql.connector
from decimal import *

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'xxx', database='begin')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

query_deal_info = ("SELECT mrp, qty_remain, deal_price, qty, asp FROM deal_info WHERE deal_id = %s")
deal_id = int(input("Enter the deal id:"))
cursor.execute(query_deal_info,(deal_id,))
query_profile = ("SELECT user_id, abp1, abp2, abp3, abpf FROM profile WHERE user_id = %s")
user_id = int(input("Enter the user id:"))
cursor.execute(query_profile,(user_id,))

for (mrp, qty_remain, deal_price, qty, asp) in cursor:
 print("The MRP for the deal is {}".format(mrp))
 print ("The deal price is {}, asp is {} and qty is {}".format(deal_price, asp, qty))

for (user_id, abp1) in cursor:
  print("The ABP1, 2, 3 and f for the deal is {}, {}".format(user_id, abp1))

cursor.close()
cnx.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the MySQL.connector [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursorbuffered.html), you need to fetch results before executing any other statement:

> In this case, you must be sure to fetch all rows of the result set
>   before executing any other statements on the same connection, or an
>   InternalError (Unread result found) exception will be raised.

So simply run your looped print lines after `cursor.execute()`:

```
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password = 'xxx', database='begin')
cursor = cnx.cursor()

# DEAL INFO
query_deal_info = "SELECT mrp, qty_remain, deal_price, qty, asp \
                    FROM deal_info WHERE deal_id = %s"
deal_id = int(input("Enter the deal id:"))
cursor.execute(query_deal_info,(deal_id,))

for (mrp, qty_remain, deal_price, qty, asp) in cursor:
    print("The MRP for the deal is {}".format(mrp))
    print ("The deal price is {}, asp is {} and qty is {}".format(deal_price, asp, qty))

# PROFILE
query_profile = "SELECT user_id, abp1, abp2, abp3, abpf \
                  FROM profile WHERE user_id = %s"
user_id = int(input("Enter the user id:"))
cursor.execute(query_profile,(user_id,))

for (user_id, abp1) in cursor:
    print("The ABP1, 2, 3 and f for the deal is {}, {}".format(user_id, abp1))

cursor.close()    
cnx.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Appreciate it. I tried your suggestion but still getting the same error. But when I try to execute only one (either deal info or profile), I'm able to retrieve it successfully. The reason I want to retrieve from two tables is I want to compare values from two tables (if deal_price > abp1).

Comment: This is the error I'm getting. Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/raghu/Desktop/a.py", line 19, in <module>
    profilecursor.execute(query_profile,(user_id,))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 485, in execute
    self._connection.handle_unread_result()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 1057, in handle_unread_result
    raise errors.InternalError("Unread result found")
mysql.connector.errors.InternalError: Unread result found

Comment: I revamped my earlier answer. No need of differently named cursors. Per the docs, you need to fetch before executing another query statement.  For `pymysql` this is not needed.